# Failing to connect to my RabbitMQ node thats being run on a VM using erl from my host machine

Tags: docker, docker-compose, erlang, erlang-shell, epmd

I'm needing to create a basic CTF using docker-compose that will be spun up on a separate machine. I have been given a service that I have to misconfigure, which will lead to a second vulnerability to get the flag or root etc. My service is Erlang's EPMD and basically the misconfig is to keep the auth cookie default which creates a random 20 character A-Z string, so it should be easy to bruteforce. Misconfiguration aside, even when I set the cookie to a specific string, I cannot connect using erl from my host machine. I've tried all I could find and it always returns with "Shell terminated." The frustrating part is I know it can connect, I used a script from the erl-matter git repo and it authed and created a shell. However I can't connect with:

```
$ erl -sname test -setcookie topsecret -remsh rabbit@<hostname>
```

This is the file I'm using:

```
version: "3.5"
services:
    rabbitmq:
        image: rabbitmq:3-management-alpine
        container_name: "sloth_ctf"
        environment:
            RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE: topsecret
            RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: admin
            RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: notadmin
        ports:
            - '5672:5672'
            - '15672:15672'
            - '4369:4369'
            - '25672:25672'
```

If you need anymore info or clarification I'll try my best to explain.